# Django: in template tag what does cl mean?

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

In django admin change list template there is a block:

```
  {% block result_list %}
      {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
      {% result_list cl %}
      {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
```

I would like to know what does `{% result_list cl %}` do, i.e. what does `cl` mean? I couldn't find it in docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a context variable name being used in an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

`result_list`'s [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L311) comment states that it  "Displays the headers and data list together".

Comment: inclusion tag link is dead, here is the link to the current page: [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 4):

It's a [`Changelist`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L37): the list of your model instances. Django uses it to handle the filtering and pagination tasks.

Answer (score 3):

`cl` isn't a general thing; it's the name of a variable, so it wouldn't be in the documentation. In *this particular case*, it's a variable holding a Changelist object, but only because that is what is passed in to the template context.